# Sending test mail fails in confluence

Tags: smtp, confluence, mail-server

I need to evaluate notification functionality in confluence.
I have installed confluence locally on my PC.

I have configured mail server in it by going to General Configuration->Mail Servers->Add a new SMTP mail server

I have provided smtp.office365.com as Server Host Name and 587 as Server port.
I have used my company user id as User name and corresponding password.

However when I try to send a test mail, it fails with below exception

```
"Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP    host: smtp.office365.com, port: 587" and also we have tried to configure our smtp server and getting error as "Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect"
```

I have seen accepted answers for this question at post  https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/139025/error-while-configuring-mail-server

However that is related to a bug Java1.7 whereas I am using Java1.8.

Can someone please suggest any idea what thing can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the hostname it seems that the mail server is in the internet. If you are behind a proxy you will need to configure this in the java options as described here

https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-web-proxy-support-for-confluence-117068.html